# What is the task of module.config() in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

What is the task of the module.config() in angularJS. I have searched on the google but i could not find the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try to read documentation?

`anuglar.module().config()` - Use this method to register work which needs to be performed on module loading

- https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies
- https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe

Comment: oh my bad. I have not notice it

Answer (score 0):

config() function executes before any other functions.So config() function is used for routing in angular.
For more details you can see [thinkster.io](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/config-function)
[angularjs.org](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module)